# Marklogic XDMP-XDQPINVREQ error

Tags: marklogic

Does any one have any idea what `com.marklogic.xcc.exceptions.XQueryException: XDMP-XDQPINVREQ` error stands for?
I could not find any reference for the same.
I am getting this error and at the end it prints "`Invalid XDQP request`".

Any help would be gretly appreciated.

The xquery that i am running is an `xdmp:estimate` on a `cts:search` query

Harry

Answer (score 3):

XDQP is the network protocol MarkLogic uses between nodes.  That error says that a node saw a request from another that was "invalid", either malformed or asking something that it doesn't understand.

This could happen if you have different versions of MarkLogic installed within your cluster.  They should all be the same version.

If that's not it, look in ErrorLog.txt and see what the "size" is of the problematic request where the error happens (it's output next to the error).  If the size is really large that could be the cause, and something to bring up with MarkLogic support.

If not, then post the full ErrorLog.txt line so I can know more.